# Connect SQL Server to a "NoSQL" Database

Tags: sql-server, database, nosql, hadoop, cloudera

I'm currently doing a business intelligence research about connecting Microsoft SQL Server to a nosql database.

My target is to import data from a nosql table to a relational DWH based on SQL Server.

I found the following approaches:

- [Microsoft Hadoop Connector](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27584)
- [Hadoop Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com)
- Building an individual script and create an xml and include it via Integration Services (not really satisfying)

If somebody did something like this before or knows some kind of "best practices". It doesn't matter wich NoSQL system is used

Answer (score 1):

NoSQL, by "definition", does not have a standard structure.  So, depending on what NoSQL backend you are trying to import from, you will need some custom code to translate that into whatever structured format your data warehouse expects.

Your code does not have to generate XML; it could directly use a database connection (e.g., JDBC, if you are using Java) to make SQL queries to insert the data.